# Type mismatch when writing a Functor instance for Either

Tags: haskell

Following the exercises in the Typeclassopedia, I tried to implement an instance of Functor for Either. My first attempt was the following:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right a) = Right (f a)
  fmap _ left = left
```

This raises the following compile-time error:

```
functor.hs:7:17:
Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘b’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
         fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Either a a1 -> Either a b
       at functor.hs:6:3
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Either a a1 -> Either a b
      at functor.hs:6:3
Expected type: Either a b
  Actual type: Either a a1
Relevant bindings include
  left :: Either a a1 (bound at functor.hs:7:10)
  fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Either a a1 -> Either a b
    (bound at functor.hs:6:3)
In the expression: left
In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap _ left = left
```

The easiest way to solve this is to replace the second definition of `fmap` like the following:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right a) = Right (f a)
  fmap _ (Left a) = Left a
```

Can someone explain me why the error is solved by explicitly pattern-matching in the second definition of `fmap`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that you're changing the type of the `Left a` even when you aren't changing the values inside it.  Note that for `Left 1 :: Either Int String`, `fmap length (Left 1)` has type `Either Int Int`.  Even though only one integer appears in the value of `Left 1`, it's type has changed because the other type parameter changed.

This is similar to the following case:

```
> let x = [] :: [String]
> x == fmap length x
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: [Char] -> String
  Actual type: [Char] -> Int
In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘length’
In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘fmap length x’
```

Even though both values are the empty list, the lists have different types.  `x` has type `[String]` and `fmap length x` has type `[Int]`.  Since equality has the type `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, you see that you can't compare values of two different types for equality since it's the same `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the third line:

```
fmap _ left = left
```

The term `left` in the left-hand side has type `Either a a1`, and right-hand side is expected to have type `Either a b`. Furthermore, `a1` and `b` are not expected to unify, because the type of `fmap` is `Functor f => (a1 -> b) -> (f a1 -> f b)`, or, specifically for this instance, `(a1 -> b) -> (Either a a1) -> (Either a b)`. Hence the type error.